# create symbology categories automatically

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, symbology

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

I'm creating a model that takes an Excel file with coordinates.

input = Table

input excel

1. make XY event
2. copy feature

output = Shapefile

Now I want to automatically add the shp and symbolize by category with a specific field.

[image]

Does a way to do this exist with
ArcPy as script added to the model ?  If so, how to do it? Or does a tool to exist to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called "[apply symbology from layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006n000000)" that you can use for reusing an existing symbology. You therefore need to save the symbology once as a .lyr file (right click > save as layer file). Note that you first need the tool "make feature layer" to create a layer on which you can apply a symbology.

For more control on you symbology in a script, there is all you need in the [arcpy.mapping](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000032000000) module